# Finding a function $f(x)$ such that $\lim _ {x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^2} = 5 $ , but $\lim _ {x \to 0 } f(x) $ doesn't exist

Tags: calculus, limits, examples-counterexamples

I need to find an example of a function $f(x)$ such that
$\displaystyle \lim _ {x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x^2} = 5 $ , but $\displaystyle \lim _ {x \to 0 } f(x) $ doesn't exist.

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: Such a function $f$ does not exist. Could you prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ Take the limit as $\rm\:x\to 0\:$ of $\rm\: f(x)\, =\, x^2 \dfrac{f(x)}{x^2}\ $ using the limit product rule.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! there was indeed a mistake in the question's formulation